# In Haskell, get a String and a Int from a String

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function in Haskell, which can do something like that:

```
getString:: String -> (String,Int)
getString "sum(6)" = ("sum",6)
getString "function1(10)" = ("function1",10)
```

It can take in a string which is a function name along with the parameter, and get a tuple of (function name, the parameter).
I wonder how can I do it in Haskell.Please give some advise.Thanks!
Let's assume that all input is in perfect form like "sum(6)"

Comment: What are `getString "  f(1)"`, `getString "f  g(1)"`, `getString "f ( 1 )"`, `getString "f"`, `getString "f6"`, `getString "(1)(2)"`, `getString "f((1))"`, and `getString "(1)"`? You have to really think through the details before you start writing code.

Comment: What is perfect form? Is `getString "(((3)"` supposed to be `("((", 3)`, or is that an error? You have to think through what you want in much more detail before you can translate that idea into a computer program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Giving your function this type is a bit misleading, because there are many input strings for which you could not produce a correct output: what is

```
getString "f1i     sh??"
```

supposed to return? So, generally we would enrich the output type in some way to indicate that it can fail: for example

```
getString :: String -> Maybe (String, Int)
```

Having done that, I recommend the use of functions like `break` or `span` to do the parsing for you. Something like this:

```
import Data.Char (isAlphaNum, isDigit)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

getString :: String -> Maybe (String, Int)
getString s = case span isAlphaNum s of
  (f, '(':arg) -> case span isDigit arg of
    (x, ")") -> ((,) f) <$> readMaybe x
    _ -> Nothing
  _ -> Nothing
```